# continue button and add button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I need you help, I have a form in PHP, javascript, HTML and MYSQL. I use a bootstrap for template.

I have a two button (continue button and add button)

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="PHP/GuardarMetodoque.php" method="POST" novalidate>
              
              
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button> 
            <input type="hidden" name="metodoque" value="metodoque" /> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Añadir Riesgo</button> 
            <input type="hidden" name="Anadirriesgo1" value="Anadirriesgo1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ID_proceso" value="<?php echo $_id; ?>">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Regresar" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the continue button serves to pass another page and the add me button works to add data from the answered form.

as you see called the file "PHP/GuardarMetodoque.php" and it works but when you click continue, you save the form again, and what I want is for you to just send me the other form without saving anything

Comment: WHat do you mean by _but when you click continue, you save the form again,_

Answer (score 0):

If you set button type to submit for continue button it will submit the form to mentioned action url, Try:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" id="continue">Continue</button>`

Add jquery to handle button click event:

`$('#continue').click(function(){ 
        //do your logic here
 });`